# ng2-ckeditor ngModel doesn't update, events not firing

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I've successfully plugged in `ng2-ckeditor` into my application, and the editor loads with the text supplied via `ngModel`.  However when I type, the value in `ngModel` doesn't change, and the `change` and `editorChange` events don't fire.  The `ready` event does fire.

Consider the following:

```
  <ckeditor
    [(ngModel)]="testContent"
    [config]="editorConfig"
    (change)="onChange($event)"
    (editorChange)="onEditorChange($event)"
    debounce="500">
  </ckeditor>

editorConfig = {
  skin: 'bootstrapck',
  height: 400,
  extraPlugins: 'divarea'
};
```

At first I was building multiple ck-editors by `ngFor`ing through an observable list, but was finding that the model content wasn't being fired.  I simplified it down to the above without it being in a loop, but it's still not working.

Am I mis-understanding how this is supposed to work, or could this be a bug?

- angular 6.1.4
- ng2-ckeditor 1.2.1
- ckeditor 4.10.1

Comment: if you are editing in source, (change) will not fire just fyi, I ran into that. I would start by making sure you have a method in your component like this onChange(e){console.log(e)} and see if you can get console logs on key strokes, that event should fire in non source edit for each keystroke.

Comment: correction, that event should fire de-bounced on key strokes, not every keystroke.

Comment: @Marshal I've already got those methods on my component :) Nothing is happening on those events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seemed to be around the build of ckeditor I'd created from the website.  I re-downloaded ckeditor (without doing the custom build), manually added the skin I need and the 'divarea' plugin into the `assets` directory, then it all seems to work fine.

Comment: This exact same thing is happening to me.  The funny thing is I had it working just a few days ago and I'm not aware of any changes that I made that would affect CKEditor.    Very strange.  I'll try a re-install.

Answer (score 1):

please use (ngModelChange) instead of (change). This is a working solution. [(ngModel)] is also working.

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-ckeditor-4icdkv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: check stackblitz link.wich i give. else if u can please give a stackblitz

Comment: it works in the stackblitz that you provided, but the version in my app, those events don't fire (although (ready) does).  It must be the way it's integrated into my app or something.

Comment: can you mebtion the version

Comment: I have check that. No errors occured. if u can demostrate your project in stackblitz i think i can help.

Comment: I've tried to implement it in stackblitz, but unable to get it to work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nj799x - Edit: nvm, it hadn't saved my change of adding the module to the module.ts.

Comment: So it works fine in stackblitz, but not in my project.

Comment: Ok. i have edited that. check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nj799x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: just clone this project and do npm install. i think that is the best way.

Comment: Think I've figured it out.  I'd built ckeditor from the website and put it into my `assets` directory.  When link directly to the link we used in stackblitz, it works.

Comment: ah you have to get it from node modules.

Comment: however (change) is not working iI think. you have to use ngModelChange

Comment: I've re-downloaded ckeditor into `assets` from the website and added the skin I need, it's working fine now!  `(change)` is working for me.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, that's great :)